# Change the int values with buttons

Tags: android, int

I have 4 int for time

```
int delay;
int period;
int delay1;
int period1;
```

they are taking control of these methods:

```
cameraOn();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            cameraOff();
        }
    },delay1,period1);



    Timer timer2 = new Timer();
    timer2.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            cameraOn();
        }
    },delay,period);

        }
```

These methods are doing the flash camera blink all the time, and what I want is with two buttons I have, change the speed of the blink, now they're like this:

```
case R.id.btslow:
        delay = 2400;
        period = 2400;
        delay1 = 1200;
        period1 = 2400;
        break;

    case R.id.btfast:
        delay = 600;
        period = 600;
        delay1 = 300;
        period1 = 600;
        break;
```

but they dont change the speed of the blink, how can I do it? Because if give them some valor from the begining later they don't change when I press the buttons. Thanks!!

Comment: What doesn't change when you click which buttons? Maybe it's just me, but I'm not psychic and I can't really figure out what you were trying to do. Though it seems like your problem is that you don't stop your old timers and put new ones there (just assigning the values like you did there isn't going to do anything by itself).

Comment: I'm trying to change the int values with the buttons, with that the speed of the blink will change, but if I leave 0 for the begin the methods dosen't work, and if I give them some value, they doesn't change when I press some button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the variables won't change the interval and delay of the current scheduled tasks, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3871723/1333516

Answer (score 1):

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable{

public void run()
{
cameraOff();
handler.postDelayed(this,period);
}
};handler.postDelayed(runnable,delay);
```